# Nested loops python value increment and retrieval in calculating tf-idf value of an individual file from a collection

Tags: python-2.7, nested-loops, tf-idf

I have been working on finding total tf-idf values of each files from a list of files. So far i've calculated tf-idf values of all words in each file (inside for w in words). Now i want to add the tf-idf value of each word which ultimately gives the tf-idf value for a particular file f. I am somewhat new in Python and i am experiencing some problem in doing so . Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. (for python 2.7)

```
 for f in file_list:
    (some code)
    for w in words:
        (some code)
        tf_idf = tf_value * idf_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Accumulate the total:

```
 total = 0
 for f in file_list:
    (some code)
    for w in words:
        (some code)
        tf_idf = tf_value * idf_value 
        total += tf_idf
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dict to keep track of each file's total tf_idf

```
 filewise_tf_idf = {}
 for f in file_list:
    (some code)
    for w in words:
        (some code)
        tf_idf = tf_value * idf_value 
        filewise_tf_idf[f] = filewise_tf_idf.get(f, 0) + tf_idf
```